# minimize the perimeter

Tags: calculus, optimization

Consider a window the shape of which is a rectangle of height $h$ surmounted by a triangle having a height $T$ that is $0.5$ times the width $w$ of the rectangle (as shown in the figure below). 
[image]

If the cross-sectional area is $A$, determine the dimensions of the window which minimize the perimeter.

$h=$

$w=$

Comment: If you show that you have thought about the problem yourself, you're more likely to get help. What have you tried? Why did it not work?

Answer (score 0):

The perimeter of the window as a function of $h$ can be written as,
$$ perimeter = h + h + w + 2 \sqrt{(\frac{w}{2})^2 + (\frac{w}{2})^2 } $$
$$ perimeter = 2h + w + \sqrt{2}\hspace{4pt}w $$
$$ perimeter = 2h + (1 + \sqrt{2})w $$
Also,
$$ A = wh + 2*\frac{1}{2}w w $$
$$ A = wh + w^2 $$
$$ \therefore h = \frac{A - w^2}{w} $$
$$ \therefore perimeter = 2(\frac{A-w^2}{w}) + (\sqrt{2}+1)w $$
To minimize the perimeter,
$$ perimeter' = 0 $$
$$ \therefore 2(-\frac{A}{w^2} - 1) + (\sqrt{2} + 1) = 0  $$
$$ \therefore \sqrt{2} - 1 = 2\frac{A}{w^2} $$
$$\therefore w^2 = \frac{2A}{\sqrt{2}-1} $$
$$\therefore w = \sqrt{\frac{2A}{\sqrt{2}-1}}  $$
$$ \therefore h = \frac{A - \frac{2A}{\sqrt{2}-1}}{\sqrt{\frac{2A}{\sqrt{2}-1}}} $$